# Spacy linking not working

Tags: spacy, rasa-nlu

I am using rasa.ai to build a bot. So far it was working fine but this morning I installed this [requirement](https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial/blob/master/Video%20files/requirements.txt) , then installed Spacy with below command.

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

It seemed all good with successful linking. Now when I am running my bot with below command

```
python -m rasa_nlu.train --config config_spacy.yml --data data/training-rasa.json --path projects
```

I am getting error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/Users/usename/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/data/en/vocab/strings.json'
```

To me this seems like a Spacy linking error but I don't understand why coz Spacy linking was successful from the above Spacy installation.

Any suggestion?

Comment: just  download with --force to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the [requirement](https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial/blob/master/Video%20files/requirements.txt) file is getting an older version of `Spacy`. So, I had to so `pip install rasa_nlu[spacy]` to get the latest `Spacy` (>2). That resolved the problem.